# $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ are independent, $W=\max (X,Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

$X,Y\sim U(0,1)$  are independent, $W=\max (X,Y)$.

1. How do I find the PDF of $W$?
2. How do I find the expectation of $W$ at two ways: 1. with the PDF of $W$ and **without** the PDF of $W$.

I'd like to get any idea how to solve it...
Thank you!!!

Comment: Use the definition $\max(X, Y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}X,& X \ge Y\\ Y,& X \le Y\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: @M.Vinay, how does it helps me? Thank you!

Comment: The CDF of $W$ is $F(w) = P(W \le w) = P(\max(X, Y) \le w)$. Draw the rectangular region $0 \le x, y, \le 1$, and integrate over this region to find $P(\max(X, Y) \le w)$, applying the definition of the $\max$ function.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf of $W$ is the non-negative function $f_W$ satisfying
$$
{\rm E}[u(W)]=\int_\mathbb{R}u(w)f_W(w)\,\mathrm dw\tag{1}
$$
for any bounded, measurable function $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

So in order to find $f_W$, we let $u$ be such a function. Then
$$
\begin{align}
{\rm E}[u(W)]&={\rm E}[u(\max(X,Y))]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u(\max(x,y)) f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_{[0,1]^2} u(\max(x,y)) \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=2\int_{[0,1]^2} u(x)\mathbf{1}_{x>y}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.
\end{align}
$$
The task is now to rewrite this integral into an integral of the form
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} u(w)g(w)\,\mathrm dw
$$
and recognize $g$ as the pdf. To find the expectation of $W$ without having to find the pdf of $W$, you can let $u$ be the identity in $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you! What is $u(),g()$? How they are defined?

Comment: $u$ is just an arbitrary bounded function used to characterize the pdf. So the idea here is to take such a function $u$ and express the mean ${\rm E}[u(W)]$ as an integral of the form $\int_{\mathbb{R}} u(w)g(w)\,\mathrm dw$ for some non-negative function $g$ (to be determined by you!). Having done that, we know that $g$ must be the pdf of $W$.

Comment: Stefan, your answer is perfectly phrased for someone who knows what things like bounded measurable functions are, but is far above the head of a beginner in probability theory. At the level of this question, a simpler approach might be better.

Comment: Which is why any answer using simpler methods is more than welcome. In any case, the OP is welcome to disregard all instances of "measurable" and just think of bounded functions. Then this is just calculus I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is to first find the CDF of $W$, and then differentiate the CDF to find the pdf.  The CDF of $W$, $F_W(\alpha)$, is,
by definition, the probability that $W$ is no larger than $\alpha$, that is,
$$F_W(\alpha) = P\{W \leq \alpha\} = P\{\max(X,Y) \leq \alpha\}.$$  But, if
the *maximum* of $X$ and $Y$, the *larger* of $X$ and $Y$, is no larger than
$\alpha$, then *both* $X$ and $Y$ must be no larger than $\alpha$, no? So we
have
$$P\{\max(X,Y) \leq \alpha\} = P\{X \leq \alpha, Y \leq \alpha\}.$$
What does *independence* of $X$ and $Y$ tell you about the right hand side
and its relationship to $P\{X \leq \alpha\}$ and $P\{Y \leq \alpha\}$? Does
the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are *uniformly* distributed on $(0,1)$ allow you
to *write down* the value of $P\{X \leq \alpha\}$ and $P\{Y \leq \alpha\}$
without the formality of integrating?  If you can solve all these small
steps successfully, you will have obtained $F_W(\alpha)$ and then all that
remains is to differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ to obtain the pdf.

Comment: So it's $P(X\le \alpha)\cdot P(Y\le \alpha)$?